# How do I bind Windows key using command line?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I want to map Windows key (without any additional key) on Ubuntu to be able to launch Terminal (`xterm`). I've already went through [this information](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MappingWindowsKey) but I don't know how to go from there.

How can I assign a shortcut to Windows key using command line?

**EDIT:** Output of `xmodmap -pke | grep Super`:

```
keycode  11 = 2 at 2 at twosuperior questiondown twosuperior
keycode  12 = 3 numbersign 3 numbersign threesuperior sterling threesuperior
keycode 115 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 133 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 134 = Super_R NoSymbol Super_R
keycode 206 = NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Edit your `xbindkeys` configuration, e.g.:

   ```
   nano ~/.xbindkeysrc
   ```

   and add the following lines for `xterm`

   ```
   "xterm"
       Super_L
   ```

   or for your standard terminal

   ```
   "x-terminal-emulator"
       Super_L
   ```
2. Kill all `xkbindkeys` processes

   ```
   killall xbindkeys
   ```
3. Restart `xbindkeys` with your configuration, eg:

   ```
   xbindkeys -f ~/.xbindkeysrc
   ```

---

Configure your standard terminal with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Comment: I didn't work (tried it with `xterm`).

Comment: and with `x-terminal-emulator`

Comment: Neither with `x-terminal-emulator` (the command itself works fine).

Comment: Post the output of `which xterm`

Comment: `/usr/bin/xterm`

Comment: Try it with `Super_R`

Comment: Didn't work either. Does it work on your machine?

Comment: Yes, of course, I have tested it.

Comment: It works well, thanks. The problem was related to having comments in a wrong format inside my `.xbindkeysrc` file.